# ubuntu 13.04 did not load after installing

Tags: 13.04

i tried installing ubuntu 13.04 on my hp pavilion g6 notebook which came with windows8 pre-installed.
i tried it with a DVD and choose "erase everything and install ubuntu"
afer installation when i reboot my pc it did not load ubuntu instead shown a screen like
"boot image did not authenticate press entre to continue"
on pressing entre it shut off every time.
i tried abd tried installing it but it did not work.
so please help me how to fix this error.....

Comment: Try disabling Windows Secure Boot on the BIOS if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This.

The problem is related to secure-boot.  Here is what you need to do:

This error indicates that it is related to Secure Boot which is a new security feature with Windows 8.  Once you disable Secure Boot, hopeful the problem will go away.

1. Reboot the notebook and press F10 until the BIOS loads.
2. Check both the "boot options" and "secure boot configuration"
   sections for the ability to disable Secure Boot and enable Legacy
   Boot Support.
3. Disable Secure Boot and enable Legacy Boot Support.
4. Save the changes and reboot the notebook.
5. Verify whether the issue is resolved and let me know.

<sup>Source:HP</sup>